# The difference between 蓄着 vs 在蓄?

Tags: difference

That is the difference between:

> 蓄着胡子

and

> 在蓄胡子

As far as I understand it's:

**在蓄胡子** -- to grow a beard.

**蓄着胡子** -- to wear a beard.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Have anybody seen a list of such pairs?:
  在蓄，蓄着，
在穿， 穿着 ，
在活， 活着 ，
在试， 试着，
在睡， 睡着
Yeah, some of the words does not make sence but those are for the template.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, 在蓄胡子 sounds like the beard is still growing and may not necessarily be very long.

蓄着胡子 suggests that the beard has grown to a certain amount already and still keeps growing.

Comment: If so then what do you think about **愛着 - loving?** and  **在愛 - falling in love?** Could there be some sentences where those things are true translations?

Comment: @coobit Basically, 在 denotes 'be doing' and 着 "in a state and still keeping it".